# Questions on Riemann's explicit formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

If we consider this version of the prime-counting function
$$\pi_0(x) = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{h\to 0} (\pi(x+h) + \pi(x-h))$$ 
(with $\pi$ being the normal prime-counting function), then we can write $\pi_0$ as
$$\pi_0(x) = \sum_n\frac{1}{n}\mu(n)f(x^{1/n}),$$
where $\mu$ is the Mertens function and 
$$f(x) = \operatorname{li}(x) - \sum_\rho \operatorname{Ei}(\rho \cdot \log(x)) -\log(2) +\int_x^\infty\frac{dt}{t(t^2-1)\log(t)},$$
the $\rho$ being the non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

I am wondering, if

- it is known how inacurrate the formula for $\pi_0$ gets (with absolute constants, not O notation), if we just consider all zeros with absolute imaginary part $|\Im(\rho)|<T$ for some $T>0$.
- if there is a similar formula, not for $\pi_0$, but for the $n$-th prime  number, and, if so, how much that would be affected by considering just the aforementioned selection non-trivial zeros.

Comment: I believe you meant $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function. The Mertens function is $M(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^x\mu(n)$. The integral term above can also be written as $-\sum\limits_n Ei(-2\,n\,\log(x))$ which I've found much faster for evaluation purposes.